# Highlight A1 if A2 does not equal A1, B1 does not equal B2, and so on

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

For example, I have A1 that has a formula to add the sum of multiple other cells, then A2 I enter a number each week. A1 and A2 must match, if they don't then a mistake has been made. I want Row 2 to highlight if it does not match. I can figure this out but I cannot figure how to copy that in conditional formatting to apply to B1 and B2, C1 and C2, D1 and D2, E1 and E2, and so on.

Comment: `=A1<>A2` as your formula and apply it to all all the columns in question?

Comment: if you know how to write a formula in conditional formatting, then BigBen's answer above is the solution. You can select cell A2 and then apply the conditional formatting for this cell first using the suggested formula, and then use the **format painter** to apply the same formatting to other cells in Row 2. Give it a go and if still has a question, feel free to come back to edit your question with more specific questions around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to have row 2 highlighted if any of the cells in it is different from the corresponding cell in row 1. You do not want to have highlighted only the offending cells.
The only way I know to do it, short of VBA, is to create a helping row, let's say row 3, where you put =A1=A2 in cell A3, then copy it to the entire row. Then, while cell A2 is active, select the entire row 2, and create a conditional formatting rule with formula =NOT(AND(3:3))

**UPDATE 03/04/21** Here a faster method (*no helping row*):
Select the row 2, and in the Conditional Formating, put this formula:
=SUMPRODUCT(-(1:1<>2:2))<0